# Rails fixtures or similar for creating data within an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fixtures

I want to populate a preferences table when a user is created. I can make a lash up version within the controller easily enough but would like something neater.

Can one do the same sort of thing with fixtures within a running application? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You could search for a gem. I've used https://github.com/FooBarWidget/default_value_for some time ago for a similar thing. It's a nice and clean solution.

Comment: I like that but I need a dozen or so entries all the same type so one default value won't do. Will use that gem elsewhere though thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I simple defined an array in the model and array.each -ed it. Not perhaps the most elegant but still have all the values in one place for editing.